# How to add custom Filter and Sort plugin that operates after the Query is executed?

Tags: 7, views

I have added my own custom (purely virtual - non-existing in DB) field to my View. Let's call it Hotel Count (it just prints some integer value based upon other
fields). This Field is implemented by View Plugin Handler (my custom class that
extends views_handler_field) - This works just fine.

The problem appears when I try to Filter by this custom Field or Sort by it...
It seems that Filter and Sort By handlers only operates on Query and fields that actually exist in DB...

How can I Filter by this custom Field and use Sort By on it after the Query is executed ?

Or maybe there is some way for the Filter and/or Sort By handlers to access
my customly added field ?

Please help!

Comment: Good luck, I wasn't able to find it. I doubt if it is possible, but I wish you all the best in search for answer ;)